# Eigenfunction of $T^n$ vs. eigenfunction of $T$ when $T$ is ergodic

Tags: functional-analysis, dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

Let $(X, \mathcal{B}, \mu, T)$ be an ergodic system, and suppose $f \in L^2(X, \mathcal{B}, \mu)$ is an eigenfunction of $T^n$ for some integer $n > 1$. Is it possible to write $f$ as a linear combination (finite or infinite) of eigenfunctions of $T$?

It seems like a fairly easy question (and I believe the answer is yes), but I've been stuck with this for a couple of days. Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You do not need $T$ to be ergodic for this to hold. Measure-preserving is enough. And you get finite sums.

We are interested in the unitary operator
$$
u_T:f\longmapsto f\circ T
$$
on $L^2$ via the so-called Koopman representation.

By the spectral mapping, the spectrum of $u_T^n=u_{T^n}$ is $\sigma(u_T^n)=\{\lambda^n\;;\;\lambda\in \sigma(u_T)\}$. In particular, if $\mu=\lambda^n$ is an eigenvalue in the latter, we have
$$
\{0\}\neq \mbox{Ker}(u_T^n-\mu Id)=\bigoplus_{\lambda^n=\mu}\mbox{Ker}(u_T-\lambda Id). 
$$
So any eigenfunction of $u_T^n$ is a finite sum of eigenfunctions of $u_T$. Not every summand of the rhs decomposition must be nonzero, but at least one must be.

**Note:** the above really is for the case $\mu\neq 0$ and is due to the fact that $X^n-\mu$ has $n$ distinct roots. Since $u_T$ is unitary, so is $u_T^n$ and their spectra are both contained in the unit circle. So the case $\mu=0$ never occurs. The lemma we used is, for an operator $u$, and a polynomial $p(X)=\prod_{j=1}^np_j(X)$ whose factors are pairwise coprime, the one that says: $$\mbox{Ker}\,p(u)=\bigoplus_{j=1}^n\mbox{Ker}\,p_j(u).$$

Comment: Just to add to Julien's excellent answer, recently, there has been a flurry of activity in dynamical systems community related to the Koopman operator. For instance, see: http://arxiv.org/abs/1206.3164

Comment: Thanks! I suppose if $T$ is ergodic, then $Ker(u_T - \lambda Id)$ is one-dimensional for each $\lambda$, but that wouldn't prevent us from writing $f$ as a linear combination of eigenfunctions.

Comment: @AkiraMotomura Right, whether $T$ is ergodic or not does not change the fact you want.